# Rake db:migrate duplicate with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise, rake

So i'm having some issues with migrations in rails.. i have 2 migrations one to add the users table and one to add devise to users...

now im getting this error when i try run

`rake db:migrate`

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL`

which tells me that both migrations are trying  to add the column email to the users table..

***USER TABLE CREATE MIGRATION***

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :email
    t.string :password_digest

    t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

***DEVISE ADDED TO USERS MIGRATION***

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

im assuming its the

```
add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
```

line in the 2nd migration causing this issue... but im just curious... is that line even relevant to devise? i can't find anything relating to this in the documentation... so if I were to delete those 2 lines would that have any effect on the way ***Devise*** runs??

Comment: dont add divise to user like that. migrate User first then add devise after.

Comment: Devise assumes it needs to add its fields to the user table. You should modify one of the migrations to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create column `email` twice: in your own migration and in devise. Also, you don't need `password_digest` column. Second time you got an error because the column already exists.

My advice is to rollback on version before creating users (rake db:rollback VERSION=timestamp_from_migration_filename), remove email and password_digest from your CreateUsers and try again all migrations.

Answer (score 0):

change_column helper is for making multiple alteration on a single table. It always try to add column.

Please check the details on [api-dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table)